# Invalid Identifier on Where Clause PL/SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause

Trying to perform a query on data in a table. The query is 'Give album title, album release date and album price of all Neil Young’s albums released after 1st January 2015.'

The relevant structure of the table (excluding other parts) is as follows:

```
create or replace type artist_type as object 
(artistName     varchar(50), 
 artistRole     varchar(25))
/ 
create type artist_array_type  
as varray(5) of artist_type
/ 
create or replace type album_type as object 
(albumTitle         varchar(50),
 albumPlaytime      number(3), -- minutes
 albumReleaseDate   date, 
 albumGenre         varchar(15),
 albumPrice         number(9,2),
 albumTracks        number(2),
 albumArtists       artist_array_type,
 albumReviews       review_table_type,
member function discountPrice return number,
member function containsText (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2) return integer)
not instantiable not final 
/
```

The below is my current query,

```
select a.albumtitle, a.albumreleasedate, a.albumprice
from albums a 
where a.albumartists.artist_type.artistname = 'Neil Young' 
    and a.albumreleasedate >= '1-Jan-2015';
```

however upon attempting to execute it in Oracle SQL Developer I get the error:

ORA-00904: "A"."ALBUMARTISTS"."ARTIST_TYPE"."ARTISTNAME": invalid identifier

904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Join can never be the solution for this.